# NodeJS: Windows could not pick up message from Azure ServiceBus

Tags: node.js, windows, message, azureservicebus, servicebus

I was using Linux docker before with NodeJS script that could handle Azure ServiceBus message successfully.

However, now I use Windows docker/simple run on Windows with same code, below error message came out even I checked there were messages on queue:

> No messages to receive

Code for Reference:

```
let azureSb = require('azure-sb'), 
connectionString = 'xxxxx',
serviceBusService = azureSb.createServiceBusService(connectionString);

serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(PDF_PRINT_QUEUE, {isPeekLock: true}, (error, message) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('OK');
    ......
}
```

Below are my main NodeJS packages that I use:

```
# npm list --depth=0
+-- adal-node@0.2.1
+-- azure-keyvault@3.0.5
+-- azure-sb@0.11.1
+-- azure-storage@2.10.3
+-- http@0.0.0
+-- puppeteer@1.20.0
`-- puppeteer-core@1.20.0
```

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues).

Comment: hi @JoeyCai, I followed that document already before when I try to run on Mac/Linux. But now I would like to run on Windows but with error (could not get message from ServiceBus Message Queue)

Comment: I test with `azure-sb@0.11.1` it works for me so I guess it's not the code problem. Maybe you could try with [azure/service-bus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's the problem with azure-sb library, it seems to work fine for me in windows. However, I'd recommend using the latest library that is based on AMQP which is better performant.

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus libraries and landed here, refer to the links below.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus`(based on AMQP) has been published.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)